# re.MatchObject.span() Method in Python

Tags: python, regex

It's written in various sites that re.MatchObject.span() Method returns a tuple containing starting and ending index of the matched string. But why does re.MatchObject.span() Method in Python in reality returns a tuple in which first element is the starting position of the matched string but the last one is not actually the ending position but ending position + 1?
For example, why does this code snippet returns (0,6) instead of (0,5)?

```
match_object = re.match(r'(\d+)',
                        '457573')
print(match_object.span())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end index is the index that you would use in a string slice to get the matched substring. In slice notation, the end index is exclusive, i.e. the index *after* the last character of the substring. So the end index returned by `.span()` also adds 1 to the last index.